# Run a test suite with different parameters? (pytest)

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

There is a set of UI tests in one class:

class TestMainPage(object):
login = 'login'
password = 'password'

```
def test_open_site(self, browser, url):
    """Opening browser and go to website"""
    browser.go_to_site(url)
    browser.check_open_auth_page()


def test_authorisation(self, browser):
    """Аuthorization on the website"""
    browser.authorisation(login=self.login, password=self.password)

...
```

How do I run this class with different parameters for one test session in turn? Parameterization of the function is not suitable, since this test will be performed independently and only after that it will move on to the next test

I found this solution:

```
my_list = [1,2,3]


@pytest.fixture(scope="session", params=my_list)
def my_params(request):
    return request.param


class Test_suite:

    def test_1(self, my_params):
        assert 1==1

    def test_2(self, my_params, ):
        assert 1 == 1


    def test_3(self, my_params, ):
        assert 1 == 1
```

It is executed alternately, which is what I need:

> test.py::Test_suite::test_1[1]
>
> test.py::Test_suite::test_2[1]
>
> test.py::Test_suite::test_3[1]
>
> test.py::Test_suite::test_1[2]
>
> test.py::Test_suite::test_2[2]
>
> test.py::Test_suite::test_1[3]
>
> test.py::Test_suite::test_2[3]
>
> test.py::Test_suite::test_3[3]

But when the second parameter is added, chaos begins(actual result):

> test.py::Test_suite::test_1[1] PASSED
>
> test.py::Test_suite::test_2[1-1] PASSED
>
> test.py::Test_suite::test_3[1-1] PASSED
>
> test.py::Test_suite::test_2[2-1] PASSED
>
> test.py::Test_suite::test_3[2-1] PASSED
>
> test.py::Test_suite::test_1[2] PASSED
>
> test.py::Test_suite::test_2[2-2] PASSED
>
> test.py::Test_suite::test_3[2-2] PASSED
>
> test.py::Test_suite::test_2[1-2] PASSED
>
> test.py::Test_suite::test_3[1-2] PASSED
>
> test.py::Test_suite::test_2[3-2] PASSED
>
> test.py::Test_suite::test_3[3-2] PASSED
>
> test.py::Test_suite::test_2[3-1] PASSED
>
> test.py::Test_suite::test_3[3-1] PASSED
>
> test.py::Test_suite::test_1[3] PASSED
>
> test.py::Test_suite::test_2[3-3] PASSED
>
> ...

I also need a conclusion in order (expected result):

> test.py::Test_suite::test_1[1] PASSED
>
> test.py::Test_suite::test_2[1-1] PASSED
>
> test.py::Test_suite::test_3[1-1] PASSED
>
> test.py::Test_suite::test_2[1-2] PASSED
>
> test.py::Test_suite::test_3[1-2] PASSED
>
> test.py::Test_suite::test_2[1-3] PASSED
>
> test.py::Test_suite::test_3[1-3] PASSED
>
> test.py::Test_suite::test_2[1-4] PASSED
>
> test.py::Test_suite::test_3[1-4] PASSED
>
> test.py::Test_suite::test_2[1-5] PASSED
>
> test.py::Test_suite::test_3[1-5] PASSED
>
> test.py::Test_suite::test_1[2] PASSED
>
> test.py::Test_suite::test_2[2-1] PASSED
>
> test.py::Test_suite::test_3[2-1] PASSED

And further. How to implement it?

Used script with two variables:

```
my_list = [1,2,3]

my_list_two = [1,2,3,4,5]
@pytest.fixture(scope="session", params=my_list)
def my_params(request):
    return request.param

@pytest.fixture(scope="session", params=my_list_two)
def my_params_two(request):
    return request.param


class Test_suite:

    def test_1(self, my_params):
        assert 1==1

    def test_2(self, my_params, my_params_two):
        assert 1 == 1


    def test_3(self, my_params, my_params_two):
        assert 1 == 1
```

Comment: What is the second parameter you're adding? And what do you mean by 'chaos'?

Comment: @Marco.S I supplemented my question by specifying the actual and expected results, and also added a script with two variables
Chaos is just the actual result, the variables go into disarray, out of order, not in the way I expect

Comment: I am still a bit puzzled: So you want the iteration over the logins (my_list_one) to be fixed while the iteration over the passwords (my_list_two) is executed?

Answer (score 1):

A quick google search will lead you to this [ticket](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/2846#issuecomment-339603786) where some workarounds are outlined, on of which is moving the scope of one fixture (see below) or using some pytest_modify_collection [hook](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/2846#issuecomment-339723402) but it seems like the problem you ran into is still an [open issue](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/3393)

```
import pytest

LOGINS = ["l1", "l2", "l3"]

PASSWORDS = ["p1", "p2", "p3", "p4", "p5"]

@pytest.fixture(scope="session", params=LOGINS)
def logins(request):
    return request.param


@pytest.fixture(scope="module", params=PASSWORDS)
def passwords(request):
    return request.param


def test_one(logins):
    pass

def test_two(logins, passwords):
    pass
```

Comment: I have seen this code, but it does not solve my problem in any way, no priority is used in the parameters

Comment: @FedorMarch If you already saw this you could have added it to your question ...

Comment: I apologize for my inattention! `session` and `module` - I missed this point. In general, it looks workable.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, if you change the scope of your fixtures to `function`, you'll get the result you want:

```py
import pytest

my_list = [1, 2, 3]

my_list_two = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]


@pytest.fixture(params=my_list)
def my_params(request):
    return request.param


@pytest.fixture(params=my_list_two)
def my_params_two(request):
    return request.param


class TestSuite:

    def test_1(self, my_params):
        assert 1 == 1

    def test_2(self, my_params, my_params_two):
        assert 1 == 1

    def test_3(self, my_params, my_params_two):
        assert 1 == 1
```

```
test_suite.py::TestSuite::test_1[1] PASSED                                                                                                                                                                                           [  3%]
test_suite.py::TestSuite::test_1[2] PASSED                                                                                                                                                                                           [  6%]
test_suite.py::TestSuite::test_1[3] PASSED                                                                                                                                                                                           [  9%]
test_suite.py::TestSuite::test_2[1-1] PASSED                                                                                                                                                                                         [ 12%]
test_suite.py::TestSuite::test_2[1-2] PASSED                                                                                                                                                                                         [ 15%]
test_suite.py::TestSuite::test_2[1-3] PASSED                                                                                                                                                                                         [ 18%]
test_suite.py::TestSuite::test_2[1-4] PASSED                                                                                                                                                                                         [ 21%]
test_suite.py::TestSuite::test_2[1-5] PASSED                                                                                                                                                                                         [ 24%]
test_suite.py::TestSuite::test_2[2-1] PASSED                                                                                                                                                                                         [ 27%]
test_suite.py::TestSuite::test_2[2-2] PASSED                                                                                                                                                                                         [ 30%]
test_suite.py::TestSuite::test_2[2-3] PASSED                                                                                                                                                                                         [ 33%]
test_suite.py::TestSuite::test_2[2-4] PASSED                                                                                                                                                                                         [ 36%]
test_suite.py::TestSuite::test_2[2-5] PASSED                                                                                                                                                                                         [ 39%]
test_suite.py::TestSuite::test_2[3-1] PASSED                                                                                                                                                                                         [ 42%]
test_suite.py::TestSuite::test_2[3-2] PASSED                                                                                                                                                                                         [ 45%]
test_suite.py::TestSuite::test_2[3-3] PASSED                                                                                                                                                                                         [ 48%]
test_suite.py::TestSuite::test_2[3-4] PASSED                                                                                                                                                                                         [ 51%]
test_suite.py::TestSuite::test_2[3-5] PASSED                                                                                                                                                                                         [ 54%]
test_suite.py::TestSuite::test_3[1-1] PASSED                                                                                                                                                                                         [ 57%]
test_suite.py::TestSuite::test_3[1-2] PASSED                                                                                                                                                                                         [ 60%]
test_suite.py::TestSuite::test_3[1-3] PASSED                                                                                                                                                                                         [ 63%]
test_suite.py::TestSuite::test_3[1-4] PASSED                                                                                                                                                                                         [ 66%]
test_suite.py::TestSuite::test_3[1-5] PASSED                                                                                                                                                                                         [ 69%]
test_suite.py::TestSuite::test_3[2-1] PASSED                                                                                                                                                                                         [ 72%]
test_suite.py::TestSuite::test_3[2-2] PASSED                                                                                                                                                                                         [ 75%]
test_suite.py::TestSuite::test_3[2-3] PASSED                                                                                                                                                                                         [ 78%]
test_suite.py::TestSuite::test_3[2-4] PASSED                                                                                                                                                                                         [ 81%]
test_suite.py::TestSuite::test_3[2-5] PASSED                                                                                                                                                                                         [ 84%]
test_suite.py::TestSuite::test_3[3-1] PASSED                                                                                                                                                                                         [ 87%]
test_suite.py::TestSuite::test_3[3-2] PASSED                                                                                                                                                                                         [ 90%]
test_suite.py::TestSuite::test_3[3-3] PASSED                                                                                                                                                                                         [ 93%]
test_suite.py::TestSuite::test_3[3-4] PASSED                                                                                                                                                                                         [ 96%]
test_suite.py::TestSuite::test_3[3-5] PASSED                                                                                                                                                                                         [100%]
```

Please [refer to the documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/fixtures.html?highlight=order#fixture-instantiation-order) for more information on how fixtures are ordered.

Comment: Unfortunately, even this answer is not a solution to my problem, please take a closer look at the result I expect. test_1[2] should be executed after test_3[1-5]

Comment: Oh, yes, didn't notice that... The plugin you mentioned on your answer seems the way to go.

Answer (score -1):

As it turned out, this problem has not been solved at the moment. The only (not official) the solution to this problem is to use priority parameters. This functionality is implemented in the pytest-param-priority library [pytest-param-priority](https://github.com/Sup3rGeo/pytest-param-priority) :

```
import pytest
import time
from pytest_param_priority import parameter_priority


@parameter_priority(0)
@pytest.fixture(scope="module", params=[1, 2, 3])
def number(request):
   return request.param

@parameter_priority(2)
@pytest.fixture(scope="module", params=["a", "b", "c"])
def letter(request):
   return request.param

@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def my_expensive_setup_fixture(letter, number):
   time.sleep(1)

@parameter_priority(1)
@pytest.fixture(scope="module", params=["red", "green", "blue"])
def color(request):
   return request.param

@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def intermediate_step(color, my_expensive_setup_fixture):
   pass

def test_one(intermediate_step):
   pass

def test_two(intermediate_step):
   pass
```

Managing the priority to set up tests is no longer a problem

I will try to implement a similar system and test what will come out of it.
A little later, I will add a solution specifically for my code, maybe it will be useful to someone